# Are there advantages of running my API-tests in Docker within Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have written **API-tests** in Ruby that are at present **called by ctest** for execution.
**I put all the things that I need into a Dockerfile for encapsulation.**
So the Container pulls the newest software version, puts the required licenses into the container and finally the newest version of my Ruby API-tests that do a black-box-testing of our software (non web/standalone).

I thought - well this was a good idea in case I want to share my image with others or I could also put a different amount of tests in different containers (maybe even only one per container) and thus save time when running the tests to have short feedback loops for the developers.

**Now people from within the company ask me "why do you do that this way?
Why not put the whole environment directly on a dedicated node for Jenkins to run the tests?"**

As I'm still **new to docker** I am not 100% sure whether I have started the right thing. I'm only attracted from the things I heard about Docker so far and I have the impression that I am on the right track.

**Now my question is - what do you think? 
Is this the way to go?
What would be your pros and cons regarding this strategy?**

Comment: That's what I do as well, but it would make even more sense if you pushed the image to a docker image repository as well.

Comment: You mean an internal repo within the company? Can you explain why?

Comment: Im my setup Jenkins pulls projects from git and builds images ready for production. These images are pushed to a private image repository. If the purpose is to build images it makes sense. Then it's also convenient to run tests in docker. When it comes to testing I just rely on the exit status for the container. For some people that is not good enough.

Comment: Thank you very much - makes sense to me now.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you would have to clean up the docker engine you are using as constant building will keep increasing disk space. The sheer size of some of the base images needed can make building slower. We added a separate pull through image cache to speed things up.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Made a more detailed summary as an answer. Poke there if you have comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts after doing exactly what you describe for about a year. (May contain bonus info)

If the purpose is for Jenkins to actually produce and image and push it to an image repository, it will make a lot more sense. You would normally push to a private repository in your company or to docker hub for open source projects.

There are some challenges using docker in a build system. The amount of data in docker engine keeps piling up and you need some way to clean things up. You can do a periodical `docker system purge --all` to wipe everything, but remember that this will also wipe the base images.

Another challenge is is that building and testing in docker can add extra time to each job, but this can be improved with some tweaking.

You can improve performance by setting up an [image registry as a pull through cache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/). I'd say this is mandatory anyway because docker hub is not immune to failure. We dodged a bullet last time docker hub was down during prime for 4-5 hours. There are of course other registry projects that supports this as well.

I do testing in docker as well. The services are going to run in docker, so it makes sense to test them in docker. I just rely on the exit status of the container to determine success/failure. For some people this is not enough because some test systems might use plugins that do more detailed reporting.

Another problem is how you deal with scaling. The whole idea of having nodes in Jenkins is to spread out the load. If all the nodes use the same remote engine it can get ugly pretty fast. I think the easiest solution is to run each Jenkins node on a separate host and docker engine. It would then do all the work in the docker engine its already running in. You can do that by mounting in the socket file or talking to it through TLS.

Overall I think it works great. Just be aware that you might be losing out on some of the more advanced features in Jenkins. Running tests and building locally can have some advantages, but personally I don't need them. I mainly just build images (Dependencies are ready in private/local package repositories)